# graphics in java, differences between jframe, jpanel, canvas, applet

Tags: java, canvas, jframe, applet, jpanel

I have some doubts programming graphics in java, can you help me?

now i always use (in PC with windows) a class that extends from jframe, and i override the paint method, even i use doblebuffer, etc.

but i saw that other codes add a jpanel to the jframe, and use the jpanel method paint... other codes use canvas and use paint method... or extends from an applet, and add to the applet a canvas object, and use the canvas paint method...

can you tell me why these differences? my graphics code works fine with jframe, but i will need to use it in android, maybe in android i must use applet?

thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you don't need to [learn applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) (an older web based client hosted Java environment) for Android development.

Comment: Your question is pretty general, I would suggest you take a look at the documentation of the different classes and then come back with any concrete questions.

Comment: `i always use a class that extends from jframe, and i override the paint method, even i use doblebuffer` - You should NOT override pant() of a JFrame and Swing is doubled buffered by default. `i saw that other codes add a jpanel to the jframe, and use the jpanel method paint...` - yes, custom painting on a panel is fine, however you should be overriding`paintComponent(...)`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.